# How to stop loop at limit, if limit is given. How to return new list with appended values?

Tags: python, list, function, append

I am building a function that accepts four parameters: `xs(original list)`, `old`, `new`, and `limit=None`). Given a certain value (`old`) if the old number is in the list, replace it with new value and return a new list called `new_xs`.

The fourth argument limit is an integer states the maximum number of replacements allowed. I need to only replace up    to the  first limit occurrences of `old` and leave the  rest unchanged. When `limit==None`, there's truly   no  limit (and  I replace all occurrences of `old`).
Negative or zero limit: no replacement

Example input/output:

```
xs=[1,2,3,4,5]
old= 2
new=100
new_xs=[1,100,3,4,5]


def replace(xs, old, new, limit=None):
    new_xs=[]
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if num==old:
            new_xs.append(new)
    return new_xs
```

I'm not sure how to make it stop at the limit, if there ever was a limit.

Comment: full stacktrace please. That code cannot throw indexerror

Comment: What is full stacktrace? Sorry I'm new to programming

Comment: copy of the output when you run the program.

Comment: >>> replace(xs, old, new, limit=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in replace
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> def replace(xs, old, new, limit=None):
...     new_xs=[]
...     for num in range(len(xs)):
...             if num ==old:
...                     new_xs.append(xs[new])
...     return new_xs
>>> replace(xs, old, new, limit= None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in replace
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I don't know how else to put that in. I copied and pasted what I had from python interactive mode

Comment: `new_xs.append(xs[new])`: that's not the code you posted !! since `new=100` and `xs` size is much lower, the index error is there.

Comment: o my... okay. Error is gone, but now it only returns [100]. I need it to return the full list with 2 replaced with 100

Comment: it doesn't make sense, you are iterating over the range of the length of the list and not the elements of the list so this check `num==old` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

1. You are looping over the output of `range()`, which is a new sequence of integers, not the contents of `xs`. We can just loop over `xs` directly to get the values we want.
2. You are currently only appending the value to your new `xs_new` list when the condition matches, and we want to append a value *every time*.
3. Your specified limit functionality is not implemented.

---

Explanation in the code comments:

```
def replace(xs, old, new, limit=None): 
    new_xs = []
    replacements = 0 # keep track of how many times we replace
    for num in xs:
        if num == old and (limit is None or replacements < limit):
            new_xs.append(new)
            replacements += 1
        else:
            new_xs.append(num) # appened the original value if no match
    return new_xs

print replace(xs, old, new)
```

Some example inputs/outputs:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> old = 2
>>> new = 100
>>> replace(xs, old, new)
[1, 100, 3, 4, 5]

>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2]
>>> old = 2
>>> new = 100
>>> limit = 2
>>> replace(xs, old, new, limit)
[1, 100, 3, 4, 5, 100, 2]
```

Comment: will changing the parameter limit=None to what you changed it to affect how it runs with my tester code?

Comment: Yes, because `None` is always less than any `int`

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of changing your code to just replace the value in your list, and return that. Be aware, this does not change the original list.

```
def replace(xs, old, new, limit=None):
    for index,value in enumerate(xs):
        if value==old:
            xs[index]=new
    return xs
```

Basically, it check the values in the list you give it, and then if it matches old, it changes that to the new value. enumerate() just counts for every iteration you do as well as provide the value in the list, so i can use that value to find the position the old value has in your list, and then swap it out.

So, using your values for xs, new, old:

```
xs=[1,2,3,4,5]
old= 2
new=100

new_xs = replace(xs, old, new)
```

Then `print(new_xs)` gives:
    [1, 100, 3, 4, 5]

Take note, i did not implement a limit for you, so that does nothing at the moment.

Comment: How do you implement the limit?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you feel this answer answer to be more correct than mine? Genuinely curious.

Comment: It actually executed as needed with limit.

Comment: I was not able to use limit=float("inf")):  with my tester cases

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll try another way.

Comment: @Julien So it pretty much works but it is still failing this test case because it isn't accepting 0 as the limit:  xs = [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1] replace(xs,1,-1,0)